# I can not successfully run tensorflow-gpu on anaconda python3.6 and spyder

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having a problem with TensorFlow-GPU when I try to run the following code

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

it yields this error:
[image]

And the same problem happens in here.

[image]

My CUDA version is 10.2,cudnn version is 7.6.5, and the TensorFlow-GPU version show on anaconda navigator is 2.0.0.

[image]

(I usually install the package on navigator)

could anyone help me?

Thank you...

Comment: Please add code as text, not as a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The letter `I` just before `tensorflow/streams_executor...` means that you're getting INFO-level log message, and Spyder mistreats this info message as the error. Getting this message is ok, however, your can perform additional checks on your GPU by running the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
# Create some tensors
a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
print(c)
```